# git push to git forked repo, but to a branch

Tags: git, github

I cloned from a repo the master branch.
I made some changes to my local. Now my repo is a copy of master branch.
Henceforth I would like to commit my code to the original but not a master branch a 'test' branch.
When I would do a git pull, it'll pull changes from the master branch but I don't want that. I want changes from test branch.
If I `git checkout test`, since it's a branch at the forked repo does not show up. What else could I possibly do?

Answer (score 2):

```
git push -u <remote> <localbranch>:<remotebranch>
```

so for example:

```
git push -u origin mybranch:mybranch
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set up a local tracking branch for the remote `test` branch, then I think you could do something like (may have syntax errors):

```
git pull origin/test test
```